# Is it possible to have different UIs for dekstop and salesforce1 when creating a record on opportunity?

Tags: page-layout, salesforce1-platform

I'm going to create a new mobile UI for opportunity creation page. And I need to reduce some fields on opportunity page in mobile but not in desktop page layout. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible and highly recommended. You can have separate page layouts for mobile and for desktop. Rather than trying to explain here, I'm going to refer you to two different documents for the details that will give you what you'll want need to know.

- [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/)
- [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/)

Between the two, you should have all the resources you need to do what you're asking about, plus much more.

**Edit**

The easiest way of setting a different layout is to use the "Mini Page Layout" which can be customized to limit the number of fields sent to a mobile device from a standard page. You can also create a Flex Page to be used in place of a VF page. Another option is to use browser detection. With browser detection, you can deliver different content to a desktop than to a mobile device. There are multiple solutions to the issue at hand.

**Edit 2**

This answer applies to the time period before Lightning Experience for desktop became available and is not a valid answer for Salesforce Mobile under LEX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the article we can create a new page layout for mobile. But when I set it on page layout assignment it will affect for the desktop page also. Where can we set one page layout for desktop and one page layout for salesforce1 on the configurations?

Comment: The easiest way of setting a different layout is to use the "Mini Page Layout" which can be customized to limit the number of fields sent to a mobile device from a standard page. You can also create a Flex Page to be used in place of a VF page. Another option is to use browser detection. With browser detection, you can deliver different content to a desktop than to a mobile device. There are multiple solutions to the issue at hand.

Comment: @crmprogdev I think this answer can be very misleading, because actually you can NOT have two different page layouts (on for mobile and one for LEX) for the very same user at once. See: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ - and AFAIK mini page layout do not really help.

Comment: @Uwe, If you look at the date of the question, it was accurate at the time it was written, which was before LEX Desktop existed. I agree that it is no longer accurate for the current UI where Lightning is now available on the Desktop. Note also that Salesforce1 Mobile is no longer how Salesforce Mobile is branded. We live in an ever changing environment.

Comment: @crmprogdev agreed. Maybe you can put a small hint inside your answer?